# knockout: data binding to individual text box in a foreach binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here's the relevant code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: chats, visible: chats().length > 0">
    <input data-bind='value: $parent.newCommentText' />
    <a href="#" data-bind='click: $root.addComment'>Add comment</a>
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
self.newCommentText = ko.observable()
self.addComment = function(chat) {
            var newComment = { CourseItemDescription: self.newCommentText(), };
            chat.CommentList.push(newComment);
            self.newCommentText("");
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("AddComment")",
                data: ko.toJSON(newComment),
                type: "post", 
                contentType: "application/json"
            });
        };
```

The problem is that this will put whatever I type in one text box in all the other text boxes. How can I make it so that it only binds to the textbox that the user is typing in and have that data available to the addComment function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each chat to be able to have their own comment field to add, then you would want to add your `newCommentText` field to the `chat` object rather than the parent.  Then you can read it and clear it out off of the `chat` object that is passed to `addComment`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put the newCommentText inside the chats array.

so the code would become

```
self.addComment = function(chat) {
            var newComment = { CourseItemDescription: chat.newCommentText(), };
            chat.CommentList.push(newComment);
            chat.newCommentText("");
           ...
        };
```